# techniques of proving a system of non-linear equations has no solution in a given domain

Tags: systems-of-equations, problem-solving

I was trying to prove that the following systems of non-linear equations have no solution in a given domain in the past a few weeks. But has no clue. The problem is the following: prove
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
\frac{2(1-\alpha)^3}{3(1-\beta)^3}+\frac{(2-\alpha)^3}{3(2-\beta)^2}+\frac{\alpha(1-\alpha)^2}{1-\beta}-\frac{\alpha(2-\alpha)^2}{2(2-\beta)}-\frac{(1-\alpha)^2(2+\alpha)}{3(1-\beta)^2}=0,\\
\frac{(2-\alpha)^3}{12(2-\beta)^3}\left(5\alpha-2-\beta(3\alpha+2)/2\right)-\frac{(1-\alpha)^3}{12(1-\beta)^4}\left(\beta^2(3\alpha+1)+4\beta(1-\alpha)-5\alpha+1\right)=0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

has no solutions in $0\leq\beta\leq\alpha\leq 1$.

I can numerically verify that this claim is true. I can even use matlab symbolic calculation tool box and it returns that there is indeed no solution in $0\leq\beta\leq\alpha\leq 1$. (But matlab symbolic calculation does not output the steps).

The algebra of these expressions are not very friendly. High orders of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Taking derivatives does not help. And both the planes (the 1st and the 2nd expressions) have positive and negative part.

I really don't know if this claim can be proved rigorously. Any comments and/or suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience at all with Matlab but I can suppose that, $f(\alpha,\beta)$ and $g(\alpha,\beta)$ being the rhs, it tries to minimize (under the given inequality constraints) the function
$$\Phi(\alpha,\beta)=f^2(\alpha,\beta)+g^2(\alpha,\beta)$$ hoping to find $\Phi_{min}=0$ (this would mean that, at least, one solution exists.

For your problem the result of such optimization is
$$\alpha=0.494090 \qquad \beta=0 \qquad \Phi_{min}=0.00108287$$

We can check for $\beta=0$.

$$f(\alpha,0)=-\frac{1}{6} (a-2)^2 (2 a-1)$$
$$g(\alpha,0)=\frac{1}{96} \left(-45 a^4+160 a^3-216 a^2+128 a-24\right)$$ but
$$9216\,\Phi(\alpha,\beta)=2025 a^8-14400 a^7+46064 a^6-89856 a^5+$$ $$122800 a^4-122368 a^3+82048 a^2-30720 a+4672$$ has no real root but its minimum is what was given above.

Comment: Thanks!  But could you please elaborate on why $\Phi$ achieves its minimum at $\alpha=0.494090$ and $\beta=0$. Did you solve it numerically?

Comment: @KevinKim. Yes, for sure ! How else do you want to handle this monster ? What you could do (I cannot since blind) is to make a contour plot of $\Phi$. To handle the constraints for the plot, I should let $\beta=k \alpha$ and allow $k$ and $\alpha$ to vary  between $0$ and $1$. I suppose that you could see the contour level $\Phi=0.002$ but, for sure not $\Phi=0.001$

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici  I see. No problem. But is there a way to prove that the optimal $\beta^*$ has to be 0 (analytically)? If that can be done, then together with what you have written down for the $f(\alpha,0)$ and $g(\alpha,0)$, I think that will be a rigorous proof.  In any case, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @KevinKim. I have typo's : *rhs* instead of *lhs* plus a bunch of *a*'s instead of $\alpha$'s. Sorry for that !